# Flutter_tex not working after flutter web deployment using firebase hosting but works fine in debug mode

Tags: flutter, web, latex, tex, flutter-tex

I am using flutter_tex package on my flutter web app.
But after deployment on firebase, the tex widget is not rendering.
It's working fine when I'm running locally from Android studio.

I've tried forcing canvaskit. But still the widget dont work.

It'll be really helpful if someone helps.

I'm using mac and everything is updated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.